# regex extract username from 2 types of url

Tags: regex

I'm currently using this regex `(?<=\/movie\/)[^\/]+`, but it only matches the username from the second url, i know i could make a if (contains /movie/): use this regex, else: use another regex on my code, but i'm trying to do this directly on regex.

1. http://example.com:80/username/token/30000
2. http://example.com:80/movie/username/token/30000.mp4

Answer (score 1):

To complete the Tensibai's answer, if you have not a port in url, you can use the last dot in url to start your regex :

```
\.[^\/\.]+\/(?:movie\/)?([^\/]+)
```

([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hs2jWm/1))

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to make the `movie/` optional and have the username in a named capture group ([Live exemple](https://regex101.com/r/0p0Rb1/1)):

```
\d[/](?:movie\/)?(?<username>[^/]+)[/]
```

using `\d/` to anchor the start of match at after the url.